# Making a java quiz and repeating a incorrect answer?

Tags: java, loops, control-flow

Im trying to create a quiz so that it asks you a question of a multiple choice, though i cant seem to figure out on how to loop it back to the incorrect question..
Im still kind of new to java programming and my understanding is unfortunately not so good..

Here is what ive currently coded,

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Quiz2
{
public static int question;
public static int question2;
public static int question3;
public static int question4;
public static int question5;

public static String guess;
public static String guess2;
public static String guess3;
public static String guess4;
public static String guess5;

public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    //create a scanner object
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hi, This is my Quiz\nYou will be asked a total of 5 questions in multiple choice format\nPlease answer as A/B/C/D (Not case sensative)", "Introduction",
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    //Asks for a paricular item from the keyboard
    guess  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "1. Which of the following is not a bright colour?\nA. Cyan\nB. Green\nC. Black\nD. Yellow\nAnswer: ", "Question 1",
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    //Asks for a paricular item from the keyboard
    guess2  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "2. What genre does the singer John Legend sing in?\nA. Pop\nB. R&b\nC. Rap\nD. Rock\nAnswer: ", "Question 2",
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    //Asks for a paricular item from the keyboard
    guess3  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "3. What is the largest discovered Star in the Universe?\nA. The Sun\nB. VY Canis Majoris\nC. Eta Carinae\nD. Beetlejuice\nAnswer: ", "Question 2",
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    //Asks for a paricular item from the keyboard
    guess4  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "4. Who is Ronaldinho Gaucho?\nA. A famous Soccer player\nB. A famous Singer\nC. The founder of Microsoft\nD. A famous Actor\nAnswer: ", "Question 2",
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    //Asks for a paricular item from the keyboard
    guess5  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "5. Who is the actor who played the role as the terminator in the movie Last Action Hero?\nA. Arnold Schwarzenegger\nB. Adam Sandler\nC. Jean Claude Van Damme\nD. Sylvester Stallone\nAnswer: ", "Question 2",
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    char x1 = guess.charAt(0);
    char x2 = guess2.charAt(0);
    char x3 = guess3.charAt(0);
    char x4 = guess4.charAt(0);
    char x5 = guess5.charAt(0);

    switch (x1)
    {
        case 'a': 
        case 'A':
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect! Cyan is a bright colour, Please Try Again..", "Answer CHECK!",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;
        case 'b':
        case 'B':
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect! Green is a bright colour, Please Try Again..", "Answer CHECK!",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;
        case 'c': 
        case 'C':
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct! Black is not a bright colour", "Answer CHECK!",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;
        case 'd':
        case 'D': 
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect! Yellow is a bright colour, Please Try Again..", "Answer CHECK!",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;
    }



    switch (x2)
    {
        case 'a': 
        case 'A':
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect! John Legend is not a Pop Singer!,\nPlease Try Again..", "Answer CHECK!",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;
        case 'b':
        case 'B':
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct! John Legend is a R&B Singer!", "Answer CHECK!",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;
        case 'c': 
        case 'C':
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect! John Legend does not Rap!,\nPlease Try Again..", "Answer CHECK!",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;
        case 'd':
        case 'D': 
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect! John Legend is not in the genre of Rock!,\nPlease Try Again..", "Answer CHECK!",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;
    }

    switch (x3)
    {
        case 'a': 
        case 'A':
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect! The Sun is the Biggest Star in our Solar System and not the Universe!,\nPlease Try Again..", "Answer CHECK!",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;
        case 'b':
        case 'B':
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct! VY Canis Majoris is currently the Largest Star Discovered in the Universe!", "Answer CHECK!",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;
        case 'c': 
        case 'C':
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect! Eta Carinae is the Second Largest Star Discovered in the Universe!,\nPlease Try Again..", "Answer CHECK!",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;
        case 'd':
        case 'D': 
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect! Beetlejuice is the Third Largest Star Discovered in the Universe!,\nPlease Try Again..", "Answer CHECK!",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;
    }

    switch (x4)
    {
        case 'a': 
        case 'A':
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct! Ronaldinho Gaucho is a famous Soccer player!", "Answer CHECK!",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;
        case 'b':
        case 'B':
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect! Ronaldinho Gaucho is not a Singer!,\nPlease Try Again..", "Answer CHECK!",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;
        case 'c': 
        case 'C':
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect! Bill Gates was the founder of Microsoft! NOT Ronaldinho Gaucho!!,\nPlease Try Again..", "Answer CHECK!",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;
        case 'd':
        case 'D': 
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect! Ronaldinho Gaucho is not an actor!,\nPlease Try Again..", "Answer CHECK!",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;
    }

    switch (x5)
    {
        case 'a': 
        case 'A':
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect! Arnold Schwarzenegger was the main actor of Last Action Hero, but in that same movie, who played the role as the terminator?\n Try Again!,\nPlease Try Again..", "Answer CHECK!",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;
        case 'b':
        case 'B':
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect! No its not Adam Sandler, but it would be funny if it was!,\nPlease Try Again..", "Answer CHECK!",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;
        case 'c': 
        case 'C':
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect! It could have been Jean Claude Van Damme!\nBut its not....\nPlease Try Again..", "Answer CHECK!",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;
        case 'd':
        case 'D': 
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct! Sylvester Stallone played the role as the Terminator in the Movie Last Action Hero!", "Answer CHECK!",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;
    }
}
}
```

Now, Using this code..
How do i create a loop for the incorrect answer?
Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You'll want to use more than one huge main method for this. Create a method for asking a question and checking the answer, returning a boolean true if the answer is correct. Call the question in a while loop and don't exit the loop until the answer is correct. Also consider using arrays to simplify your code. The key to progressing is to experiment, so do that a *lot*!

Comment: If I am in your case, I would generally create a loop for this preferably a while loop. where inside the while loop it would compare the correct answer to the users answer. on another note the you may want to fix your class. and like what hovercraft said, experiment with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is only really going to work for a very simple example and you're obviously having problems reacting to the user because you're not keeping track of state.

I wrote this up that does what you want (I think).  Look through it and let me know if you have questions about how/why things are.

https://gist.github.com/3579413

(I put it on a public gist because there's a lot of code...)  Ideally you'd split those classes out into their own files so you don't end up with a massively cumbersome file.  Hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: I just realized I didn't handle the case where they answer something that is not a, b, c or d.  You would have to handle a null coming back in `getResponse` and `isCorrect`, then bubble that up into `main`.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU!! i will take a look through it and try to understand it

Answer (score 2):

You need to extract out your question-asking code block into a separate method (or 2!). This will allow you more conveniently to call it more than once if required. This would look something like:

```
while (!askQuestionsWithAllCorrect()) {
   System.out.println("Asking again...");
}
```

You could of course give the user the *option* of re-attempting the questions inside the while loop itself.

Comment: I am wondering why does the OP want to ask a question until the user gets it right. kinda odd.

Comment: Yes, of course there should ideally be a 'parachute' clause in there as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are various looping mechanisms available to you (for, do-while, etc).  When (if ever) should the program stop looping through the questions?  Should it loop through all the questions (including the ones you have answered correctly)?

The short answer is you need to repeat the asking and checking of the questions.  Defining the questions does not need to be repeated.  So your loop (which ever one you decide to use) should surround the part of the code that (a) displays the questions [char x1=...] and then (b) checks and displays the answer [end of the switch statement].

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create a map to contain all of your questions.

```
Map<Integer, String> questionMap;
```

If a question is answered correctly, remove it from the map.  You can either use a `ConcurrentHashMap`, which will support the removal of elements from the map in a concurrent fashion:

```
questionMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String>();
// populate the map with your questions

for(Integer i : questionMap.keySet()) {
    if(t.isQuestionTrue(answer, questionMap.get(i))) {
        questionMap.remove(i);
    }
}
```

...or you can use a non-concurrent map and use the `Iterator` to safely remove elements concurrently.

```
questionMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
// populate the map with your questions

Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> it = questionMap.entrySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry entries = it.next();
    if(t.isQuestionTrue(answer, (String)entries.getValue())) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

The loop would then be established to continue running while there's an element left in your map.

```
while(questionMap.size() > 0) {
    // run through your program
}
```